# su - user Vs sudo su - user

Tags: linux, sudo, users, su

`sudo su -` will elevate any user(sudoer) with `root` privilege.

`su - anotheruser` will switch to user environment of the target user, with target user privileges

What does `sudo su - username` mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just repeating both @dr01 and @OneK's answers because they are both missing some fine details:

- `su - username` - Asks the system to start a new login session for the specified user. The system will require the password for the user "username" (even if its the same as the current user).
- `sudo su - username` will do the same, but first ask the system to be elevated to super user mode, after which `su` will not ask for "username"'s password because a super user is allowed to change into any other user without knowing their password. That being said, `sudo` in itself enforces security by by checking the `/etc/sudoers` file to make sure the current user is allowed to gain super user permissions,and possibly verifying the **current** user's password.

I would also like to comment that to gain a super user login session, please use `sudo -i` (or `sudo -s`) as `sudo su -` is just silly: its asking `sudo` to give super user permissions to `su` so that `su` can start a login shell for the super user - when `sudo` can achieve the same result better it by itself.

Comment: So.. what should be the entry in `/etc/sudoers` file? for `sudo su - foo` working...

Comment: The default on Debian style OS of giving members of the `admin` group permissions to do anything (as long as they know their own password) is: `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`. If you want to give specifically permission to run `su - foo`, then it should be `username ALL=/usr/bin/su - foo` and there are various features you can set or limit - see `man sudoers` for the full spiel and some useful examples.

Comment: @Guss - What are the differences between sudo -i and sudo -s and why choose one over another? Secondly, why use sudo -i for example when there is the option to use su -?

Comment: @Motivated: `-i` is a "login shell", while `-s` is an "interactive shell". There's a very delicate difference between the two which is mostly shell implementation dependant and has to do with initialization sequence and which setting files are loaded. Read your shell's manual page for exact details, but its also a good idea to consult `man sudo`.

Comment: Secondly: `sudo -i` and `su -` do the same thing (`su -` is equivalent to `su --login`), using different authorization mechanism: `su` verifies the password for the `root` account, while `sudo` verifies the password for your current user account and also verifies that your current user account is allowed to run administrative operations according to the `/etc/sudoers` policy. This is the reason `sudo` is prefered: it doesn't require your system to have a `root` password (which is considered insecure) and usage is subject to a finer grained security policy.

Comment: @Guss - Thanks. In reading the man page it isn't clear as to the selecting the appropriate command. For example, when should `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` be used?

Comment: I recommend only using `sudo -i` as it behaves like `su -` that everyone knows (and loves >:-( ), so there'd be fewer surprises. If your root shell is Bash, then the difference between `-i` and `-s` is that `-i` causes the profile file to be loaded while `-s` will cause the `.bashrc` file to be loaded (it is usually also loaded from the profile file) - so if you know there are settings in the profile file you'd like to skip, use `-s`. Otherwise, stick with `-i`.

Answer (score 6):

Having superuser rights, `sudo su - username` will log you in (in a login shell) as `$username` without asking for a password, while `su - username` will ask for the password of `$username`.

Comment: No need to be super user to `su - username`, if you know the passwd

Comment: From my understanding that is what I answered? You don't need to be superuser to `su`, but being super user, it won't ask you for a password of the user you want to become.Edit: after your edit, @overexchange, it makes more sense to me.

Comment: Does that mean... `sudo` is used to just give privilege as sudoer without a need of passwd? or something more than that...

Comment: `sudo` will execute the command that follows as the user with elevated rights. Hence, you might as well change the password for the `$username`, so you can become the user as well without being asked for a password.

Comment: As a sudoer...switching to target user without a passwd, but still getting elevated rights of that target user....

Answer (score 3):

`sudo su - username` does the same as `su - username`: runs a login shell as `username`.

`su - username` run as root and `sudo su - username` do not require to know *username*'s password (as they are run with elevated privileges), while `su - username` run as a normal user requires to know it.

Comment: For a user(`user1`) to run with appropriate sudo rights, What are the changes required for achieving this sudo rights?

Comment: Sudo rights are defined in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: We would not require password in former case unlike latter case

Comment: for your point: "can only be run by the superuser" If current user has passwd, then you would not need to be superuser.. Isn't it?

Comment: Apologies, what I wrote was wrong. Caffeine abstinence probably... I corrected my answer.